# How to check if an XML attribute contains a string?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Here is the XML (I have saved an html page in xml form to parse it generically:

```
<td width="76" class="DataB">2.276</td>
<td width="76" class="DataB">2.289</td>
<td width="76" class="DataB">2.091</td>
<td width="76" class="DataB">1.952</td>
<td width="76" class="DataB">1.936</td>
<td width="76" class="Current2">1.899</td>
```

Now I am trying to find all of the elements that contain the string Current because the web page changes the number on the back:

```
var xElements = xml.Descendants("td").Where(element => ((string) element.Attribute("class")).Contains("Current"));
```

This returns an `object does not exist` error here:

```
((string) element.Attribute("class"))
```

How can I check an attribute if it contains something?

Comment: Are you sure the XML don't declare default namespace?

Comment: You should take a look at [Htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). This is good library to parse Html content (and it avoids to convert and ensure a good Xhtml format)

Comment: @SteveB Actually thats where the data comes from. I created a screen scraping service that scrapes a page then converts it to an XDocument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you asked me, it would be easier to write as an xpath query.  This way you don't have to deal with cases where elements doesn't contain class attributes and other such cases.

```
var query = xml.XPathSelectElements("//td[contains(@class,'Current')]");
```

Otherwise, you would have to check for the existence of the attribute before trying to read it.

```
// query syntax makes this a little nicer
var query =
    from td in xml.Descendants("td")
    let classStr = (string)td.Attribute("class")
    where classStr != null && classStr.Contains("Current")
    select td;
// or alternatively, provide a default value
var query =
    from td in xml.Descendants("td")
    where ((string)td.Attribute("class") ?? "").Contains("Current")
    select td;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably something wrong with the XML input you're using - trying this code works for me in LINQPad:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(@"<tr><td width=""76"" class=""DataB"">2.276</td>
<td width=""76"" class=""DataB"">2.289</td>
<td width=""76"" class=""DataB"">2.091</td>
<td width=""76"" class=""DataB"">1.952</td>
<td width=""76"" class=""DataB"">1.936</td>
<td width=""76"" class=""Current2"">1.899</td></tr>");

var xElements = xml.Descendants("td").Where(element => ((string) element.Attribute("class")).Contains("Current"));

xElements.Dump();
```

Are you sure your XML is valid?

Comment: if I say (string) element.Attribute("class") == "Current" it works perfectly

Comment: Can you post more of the XML and where you're actually executing the query?

Comment: Both of those things are posted. The XML you see is the relevant data, and the query I am trying to make is the one in the code. I am not sure what more I can post?

Comment: The XML is incomplete.  You couldn't load it as is into an XDocument, it doesn't have a proper root node.  And the query is written, but not executed in the code provided (such as xElements.Dump() in LINQPad or iterating over the xElement collection)

Comment: Got ya, I am actually just taking the values I get from the List and adding the data to the DB, So that part probably isn't helpful. but one second on the data